# ATS setting NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent not working

Tags: ios, uiwebview, app-transport-security

I am trying to get the ATS setting NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent working in my iOS app and for some reason, the setting seems be be ignored. I put together a quick test app to make sure none of my other Info.plist settings were breaking things, but insecure links are still getting rejected in both UIWebViews and WKWebViews. Here are the ATS settings in my Info.plist file:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

And here is my the code in my controller with the UIWebView:

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        webView.delegate = self
        let url = URL(string: "https://www.salliemae.com/smartoption/")
        let request = URLRequest(url: url!)
        self.webView.loadRequest(request)
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You'll need to be more specific.  Allow insecure loads is not the same as allowing loading of HTTPS requests with cert problems.  Provide the error messages you are getting and some example http requests that are being made? Or is is http request for assets needed by the salliemae.com site above?

Answer (score 1):

So it looks like the issue was due to a bug in the version of Xcode I was using that wasn't respecting the NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent flag. Updating to Xcode 8.2 beta (8c30a) fixed the issue.

Comment: Mark it as accepted answer. So it will be easy to find that this question is solved.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to be more specific.
And I saw a similar question in apple developer forum，wish this could be helpful：[NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent in UIWebView](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/198714#198714)。

Comment: Hey thanks. I tried that with the current version of Xcode but it looks like there is a bug that stops that setting from actually working. It is working in the Xcode 8.2 beta (8c30a).

Comment: For more info, see this

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/54535

Answer (score 0):

You could add the following in the Info.plist file, and rerun. This would allow any arbitrary content to be loaded in the UiWebView.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>  
<dict>  
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent</key>  
    <true/>  
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>  
    <true/>  
</dict>
```